# Is it better to use latin or Japanese characters in URL?

Tags: seo, url, character-set

If I want to reach native Japanese speakers, which slug is better;
1/ english-dictionary.com
2/ 英語の辞書.com

There are several questions on this but none seem to give a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

The site I manage contains over 24 languages and many of them have non-latin characters. We decided to use the native characters for the page slugs and it seems to work for our SEO pretty well - also the search term in google is highlighted if it is contained within the slug.